# Database Design Redundant Functional Dependencies (FD's)

Tags: database, database-design, functional-dependencies

I have not understood how the following problem must be approached. 
Any help in learning how to solve this question will be much appreciated!

```
Consider Relation Schema R = {ABCDEFG} with a set of Functional Depenedencies
F = {GA -> D,   DC -> E,   GF -> A,   CA -> GB,   AF -> D,   F -> G}
Identify any redundant Functional Dependencies.
```

Comment: What does FD(s) stand for? Is it Fire Dept. or Fake Domains? I'm going to assume that it stands for a joined pair that would reference how many time the 'D' shows up in the 'F' array, which would be 2 times (GA and AF), The fact that it's more than once would make it redundant. Well that's my best guess.

Comment: Functional Dependencies

Comment: Searching for `algorithm redundant functional dependencies` quickly turns up likely links, such as [this one](http://www.cas.mcmaster.ca/~fchiang/courses/db3/asgs/asg3/FDDublin.pdf) - it's a PDF.

Comment: Egk! me sit down and take zero!! Ok, I just did a quick search also to wikipedia. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_dependency) The way it's written in your post it's hard to tell if 'ABCDEFG' is an element of R. I'm going to fantasize and pretend that they are each objects that can be mapped to. For a do over I'm going to guess that since it has to match exactly. Then I would say that GA, DC, GF, AF, and F all match that of the R set. I could be wrong again, it could just be the F -> G that match exactly.

Comment: Would this be a good question for cstheory.stackexhange? Anyway looking at your sets I would guess F->G looks like redundant since it is a transitive of GF->A and CA->GB?

Comment: Questions about functional dependencies are on-topic here.

Comment: @Tuzki: What are the steps on your lecture slides?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider GA -> D. To check whether it is redundant we need to check whether we can infer D from GA by using dependencies other than GA -> D. However, no other dependency is applicable to GA so GA -> D is not redundant.

Consider AF -> D. If we know AF, then we also know AFG since F -> G. Moreover, since GA -> D we also know D. Hence, we have inferred D from AF without using the dependency AF -> D meaning that AF -> D is redundant.

If your lecture slides also discuss redundant (extraneous) attributes you can check that G is an extraneous attribute in GF -> A since F -> G.